# Java resultSet accept may be filled with table or integer. Integer does not work

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I have a really big query in my system which has to retrieve some information from a database and process it in java. The problem is that the query returns a table full of results when it is succesful and different int error codes for the different problems that may appear. The object ResultSet is working fine when everything goes well and I obtain a table full of data, but when I obtain an error code, the ResultSet object is empty. Is ther any way around to manage the output of a query when it may be an int or a table?

The code:

```
ResultSet resultValue = commonDao
                .getResultSet(Queries.QUERY_RETURNING_TABLE_OR_INTEGER);
        try {
            resultValue.next();
            if ("1".equalsIgnoreCase(resultValue.getString(1))) {
                logger.info("Everything went well");
            } else if ("-1".equalsIgnoreCase(resultValue.getString(1))) {
                logger.error("Error number 1");
                error = true;
            } else {
                logger.error("The following data is in error:");
                while(resultValue.next()) {
                    logger.error("item_id: " + resultValue.getString(1) + " | file_id: " + resultValue.getString(2) + " | currency: " + 
                                resultValue.getString(3) + " | issue date: " + resultValue.getString(4));
                }
                error=true;
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            logger.fatal("There was a sql problem: " + e);
            error = true;
        }
    }
    return error;
```

Comment: In case of `SELECT` statements JDBC will return either `ResultSet` which is not null (and you need to check `ResultSet.next()` to know if it is empty or not) or throw an exception. Could you please add your code to the question?

Comment: What do you mean by **but when I obtain an error code, the ResultSet object is empty**